# When cable is disconnected from my Smartphone it runs old code of my React Native app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am debugging my React Native app with my Smartphone (BQ Aquaris U Plus) in my Mac.

All is right while the SmartPhone is connected to the PC.

I do successfully the 'react-native run-android' command and it execute my code.

The problem come when I disconnect the cable after have installed the App, it execute old code like 2 month ago.

I have tried all, uninstall , uninstall for all user, reboot the system, uncheck Automatic restore (Android) ... And sometimes it seems worked for me but passed 2 hours still happening the problem.

I am lost of this, I don't know what or how to search this error, I have faced it since 2 month.

It have been happening in iOS too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to distinguish between development mode and release mode.

While developing and while your device (Smartphone) is using the same network as your mac/pc your local bundle server is reachable and your code will run from there, if the local server is not reachable it will failover to the device local bundle complied previously (probably in your case I'm betting 2 month ago)

In order to work completely detached from you mac/pc you need to bundle your current code -

For iOS -

```
react-native bundle --entry-file='index.ios.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
```

For Android -

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

This will create local bundle that your app can use while disconnected from your computer and your local network.

Comment: It seems is working, but each time I change something I will have to execute the command because it only save the state when you executed the command. Anyway thanks a lot!  I will still notifying if stop working.